# Is it possible to use ApplicationIntent with Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

we host an MS SQL 2019 database using a read replica and were wondering if it is possible to use `applicationintent=readonly` in the Linked Table Manager connection string in MS Access to force it to use the read replica.

When I tried, it still allowed me to write data using the Access connection to the SQL table, so I am not sure if I did something wrong or if it is just not possible to do this in Access.

Please see connection string below:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;APP=Microsoft
 Office;DATABASE=XXX;APPLICATIONINTENT=readonly;
```

Comment: Does your replica topology include a Listener?

Comment: Yeah we have an AGL. I am able to use the read replica with SSMS and Jetbrain's DataGrip tool, just trying to get it to also work with MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation lists all the requirements
[Connect to an Always On availability group listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-ver16#ConnectToSecondary)

> Read-only routing refers to automatically routing incoming listener
> connections to a readable secondary replica that is configured to
> allow read-only workloads.
>
> Connections are automatically routed to the read-only replica if the
> following are true:
>
> - At least one secondary replica is set to read-only access, and each
>   read-only secondary replica and the primary replica are configured to
>   support read-only routing.
> - The connection string references a database involved in the
>   Availability Group. An alternative to this would be the login used in
>   the connection has the database configured as its default database.
>   For more information, see this article on how the algorithm works with
>   read-only routing.
> - The connection string references an availability group listener, and
>   the application intent of the incoming connection is set to read-only
>   (for example, by using the Application Intent=ReadOnly keyword in the
>   ODBC or OLEDB connection strings or connection attributes or
>   properties).

Since you already specify `Database` and `ApplicationIntent` in your connection query, you only need to check for the listener and the read-only routing list.

You can check the listener with this DMV:

```sql
select
    *
from sys.availability_group_listeners as agl
```

And the read-only routing list with this snippet

```sql
SELECT 
    ar.replica_server_name AS RoutingListOwner
    , arr.replica_server_name AS ReadOnlyReplica
    , arorl.routing_priority
    , arr.read_only_routing_url
    , arr.secondary_role_allow_connections_desc
FROM sys.availability_read_only_routing_lists AS arorl 
JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS ar
    ON ar.replica_id = arorl.replica_id
JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS arr
    ON arr.replica_id = arorl.read_only_replica_id
order by ar.replica_server_name, arorl.routing_priority
```

Comment: Neither of those commands seem to be possible to run in MS Access. Looking into it it seems to be due to MS Access not liking Namespaces(?)

I know the AGL is working fine as we are able to use the read replica fine in SSMS, it is just when I add that applicationintent=readonly in MS Access and then save it, refresh the connection and then try and edit I am still able to edit the DB.

Was hoping someone maybe had done it before themselves but if not then that is fine. Thanks for your comment though!